# Network-2.4.2.2 error cabal install on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal, cabal-install

When attempting to install the network package (cabal install network) on Windows Server 2008 inside of a cabal sandbox (1.18.*) I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\user\Project>cabal install network --prefix=C:\Users\user\Project
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring network-2.4.2.2...
configure: error: invalid package name: 0
Failed to install network-2.4.2.2
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
network-2.4.2.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Important to note that network is installed globally via the haskell platform, but won't install in the sandbox for a strange reason. The exact error looks like `configure: error: invalid package name: 0`

What could be prompting the package name to be 0?

Comment: Maybe it's because you're running `cabal install network` in the `cmd.exe` shell? Packages with `configure` scripts in them must be installed from under `MSYS`. Here's a guide on how to install the most recent `MSYS` version: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/Preparation/Windows/MSYS2

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov I appreciate the help. I installed MSYS and attempted to run the same commands. Still getting the same error message, not sure what's so special about `network`. I'm going to submit a bug against the library. `"configure: error: invalid package name: 0"`

Comment: `network-2.4.2.2` installs under `Cygwin`, but not the `DOS` prompt nor `MSYS` prompt for me.

Comment: Ok, it installs, but it fails during linking. Is there some kind of special flag I need to compile with, like specify the correct version of gcc? `Loading package network-2.4.1.2 ... linking ... ghc.exe: unable to load package `network-2.4.1.2'
ghc.exe: \\vboxsrv\Users_dmj_SolidTranslate\.cabal-sandbox\i386-windows-ghc-7.6.3\network-2.4.1.2\HSnetwork-2.4.1.2.o: unknown symbol `_getWSErrorDescr'
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
snap-0.13.2.4 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1`

Comment: Maybe you're using a different version of `gcc` (or `ld`) from the one that comes with GHC? Make sure that `$GHC_DIR/mingw/bin` is in `PATH` and is not overridden by some other version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MinGHC](https://github.com/fpco/minghc#readme), which provides binary installers for Windows with enough utilities that a standard `cabal install` can successfully install the `network` package.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you are installing from the Windows command prompt, you should instead use a Mingw or Cygwin shell. I find it easiest to install using [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/), then running:

```
WHICHGHC=`which ghc` && PATH=`dirname $WHICHGHC`/../mingw/bin:$PATH && cabal install network --configure-option --host=i386-unknown-mingw32 --global --enable-library-profiling
```

The full instructions, including alternative forms and feedback, are available [on this blog post](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/installing-haskell-network-library-on.html).

Comment: Neil, thanks a ton! I fixed the issue a while ago by going through your blog post. Big thanks. I use cygwin as well. Per the GHC docs it says cygwin actually calls mingw for building. `"and it uses mingw's ghc while compiling your Haskell sources (even if you call it from cygwin's bash)"` -- from `Section 13.5.2` from the GHC User Guide

Comment: error: dirname: extra operand `Files'
Try `dirname --help' for more information.

Comment: @ses I recommend installing your GHC on a path without spaces - I imagine some quoting would fix it up, but not sure where - perhaps " around `$WHICHGHC`.

Comment: For those who have "extra operand Files" error, just put $WHICHGHC in quotes, worked for me.