# Add dependency to GHCI

Tags: haskell, ghci

Can I include a dependency in GHCI.

If running cabal add to .cabal file

```
build-depends:       base >=4.7 && <4.8,http-conduit-downloader
```

Can `http-conduit-downloader` be included in GHCI ?

Update :

Runnning commands :

```
c:\Users\Adrian\Google Drive\SparkSetup>cabal sandbox init
Writing a default package environment file to c:\Users\Adrian\Google
Drive\SparkSetup\cabal.sandbox.config
Using an existing sandbox located at C:\Users\Adrian\Google
Drive\SparkSetup\.cabal-sandbox

c:\Users\Adrian\Google Drive\SparkSetup>cabal install --only-dependencies
cabal: SparkSetup.cabal:19: Construct not supported at this position: F 19
"main-is" "SparkSetup.hs\nbuild-depends: base >=4.7 &&
<4.8,http-conduit-downloader\ndefault-language: Haskell2010"

c:\Users\Adrian\Google Drive\SparkSetup>cabal repl
Package has never been configured. Configuring with default flags. If this
fails, please run configure manually.
cabal: SparkSetup.cabal:19: Construct not supported at this position: F 19
"main-is" "SparkSetup.hs\nbuild-depends: base >=4.7 &&
<4.8,http-conduit-downloader\ndefault-language: Haskell2010"
```

`cabal repl` does not start the repl ?

Update 2  :

```
c:\Users\Adrian\Google Drive\SparkSetup>cabal configure
cabal: SparkSetup.cabal:19: Construct not supported at this position: F 19
"main-is" "SparkSetup.hs\nbuild-depends: base >=4.7 &&
<4.8,http-conduit-downloader\ndefault-language: Haskell2010"
```

Update 3 :

cabal and ghci versions :

```
C:\Users\Adrian\Google Drive\SparkSetup>cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.18.0.5
using version 1.18.1.3 of the Cabal library

C:\Users\Adrian\Google Drive\SparkSetup>ghci
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude>
```

Update 4 :

SparkSetup.cabal :

```
-- Initial SparkSetup.cabal generated by cabal init.  For further 
-- documentation, see http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/

name:                SparkSetup
version:             0.1.0.0
-- synopsis:            
-- description:         
license:             GPL-2
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              USER
maintainer:          USER.COM
-- copyright:           
-- category:            
build-type:          Simple
-- extra-source-files:  
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable SparkSetup
main-is: SparkSetup.hs             
  -- other-modules:       
  -- other-extensions:    
  build-depends:       base >=4.7 && <4.8,http-conduit-downloader
  -- hs-source-dirs:      
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Line 19 :  `main-is: SparkSetup.hs`

SparkSetup.hs exists at same dir as SparkSetup.cabal, SparkSetup.hs contents are : `main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"`

Is this not correct ?

Update 5 :

updated .cabal file :

```
-- Initial SparkSetup.cabal generated by cabal init.  For further 
-- documentation, see http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/

name:                SparkSetup
version:             0.1.0.0
-- synopsis:            
-- description:         
license:             GPL-2
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              USER
maintainer:          USER.COM
-- copyright:           
-- category:            
build-type:          Simple
-- extra-source-files:  
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable SparkSetup
  main-is: SparkSetup.hs
  -- other-modules:    
  -- other-extensions:    
  build-depends:       base >=4.7 && <4.8,http-conduit-downloader
  -- hs-source-dirs:      
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Appears to have been an indentation issue (\n may also have caused issue)

But now when I run :

```
c:\Users\Adrian\Google Drive\SparkSetup>cabal install
Resolving dependencies...
Notice: installing into a sandbox located at C:\Users\Adrian\Google
Drive\SparkSetup\.cabal-sandbox
Configuring network-2.6.2.1...
Failed to install network-2.6.2.1
Last 10 lines of the build log ( C:\Users\Adrian\Google Drive\SparkSetup\.cabal-
sandbox\logs\network-2.6.2.1.log ):
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\network
-2.6.2.1-10212\network-2.6.2.1\dist\dist-sandbox-8472864c\setup\setup.hs, C:\Use
rs\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\network-2.6.2.1-10212\network-2.6.2.1\dist\dist-san
dbox-8472864c\setup\Main.o )
Linking C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\network-2.6.2.1-10212\network-2.6.2.1
\dist/dist-sandbox-8472864c\setup\setup.exe ...
Configuring network-2.6.2.1...
setup.exe: The package has a './configure' script. This requires a Unix
compatibility toolchain such as MinGW+MSYS or Cygwin.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
HsOpenSSL-0.11.1.1 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to install.
SparkSetup-0.1.0.0 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to install.
connection-0.2.5 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to install.
http-client-0.4.18.1 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to install.
http-client-tls-0.2.2 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to install.
http-conduit-2.1.7.1 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to install.
http-conduit-downloader-1.0.25 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to
install.
network-2.6.2.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
socks-0.5.4 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to install.
streaming-commons-0.1.12.1 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to install.
tls-1.3.1 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to install.
x509-validation-1.6.0 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to install.
```

Seems there is an issue with `http-conduit-downloader` package also ?

Comment: What is the cabal and ghc version you are using ?

Comment: Also just to be sure, can you run `cabal configure` first and paste the output here ?

Comment: @Sibi question updated

Comment: @Sibi cabal & ghci version added

Comment: The problem is not with `cabal repl` or `ghci`. There is a syntax error in line 19 of your `SparkSetup.cabal` file.

Comment: @duplode please see update

Comment: The error says `cabal: SparkSetup.cabal:19: Construct not supported at this position: F 19
"main-is" "SparkSetup.hs\nbuild-depends: base >=4.7 &&
<4.8,http-conduit-downloader\ndefault-language: Haskell2010"`. That `\n` looks odd - perhaps the cabal file has Unix line endings?

Comment: @duplode please see edit

Comment: `setup.exe: The package has a './configure' script. This requires a Unix
compatibility toolchain such as MinGW+MSYS or Cygwin.`

Comment: On the latest edit: There are a few complications with building the `network` package in Windows. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570952/network-2-4-2-2-error-cabal-install-on-windows) for suggestions, or just start over with the latest [Haskell platform for windows](https://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html), which includes a pre-built `network`, and then recreate your sandbox.

Comment: I would go with duplode's suggestion. Also you can try `stack` as an alternative to Haskell platform.

Comment: @Sibi Not 100% sure (I haven't tried it on Windows), but I believe the OP will run into the same issue using `stack`, as it will (try to) compile `network` anyway. (By the way, `stack` should work fine with a Haskell Platform, though that will limit your ability to use recent Stackage snapshots.)

Comment: @Sibi why delete your answer ? "cabal repl" is useful command and is related to question.