# Installation error with haskell cabal

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I'm installing haskell platform for windows 10 for the first time (https://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html) for my laptop and pc.

My PC installs fine and I can run `cabal install hsdev` without any issues. However, when I do the exact same process on my laptop the following error is raised:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring old-time-1.1.0.3...
Failed to install old-time-1.1.0.3
Build log ( C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\old-time-1.1.0.3.log ):
Configuring old-time-1.1.0.3...
configure: error: invalid package name: 0
\old-time-1.1.0.3'
cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-7388\old-time-1.1.0.3'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
old-time-1.1.0.3 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure
```

The log just repeats the stdout shown above

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe try [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/) instead..?

Comment: Ok but this should work! It's the same setup on both machines and only one of them works

Comment: ok, but I followed the directions on the haskell-platform site (modifying the config file to list msys directory).

Comment: What happens if you do `cabal install old-time` just by itself?

Comment: Same result. Stack also fails in the same way

Comment: The line `\old-time-1.1.0.3'` is pretty bizarre.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570952/network-2-4-2-2-error-cabal-install-on-windows was proposed a a duplicate (and I mistakenly supported that before changing my mind and reopening), but actually I don't think it is: the `network` package has some specific installation requirements that aren't shared by most other packages like `old-time` and the answers to that question are specific to `network`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is caused by not adding the following lines to your cabal config (discoverable by running `cabal user-config init`) as the platform instructions suggest:

```
extra-prog-path: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.2.2\msys\usr\bin
extra-lib-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.2.2\mingw\lib
extra-include-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.2.2\mingw\include
```

(with the paths set for the appropriate version of the platform.)